# ajax load shortcode in response

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form in a **page-form.php** file, on Sumbit i need to send the data to **formResult.php** to connect to db and get results (products IDs).
With Ajax in the form.php file i need to load the products IDs in a shortcode like that : **[product id="1, 2, 3"]**.

**form.php** part of getting the result from DB :

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo $row["ID"]; // it does display the IDs in page-form.php
        echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.$row["ID"].'"]'); // if i add this line, nothing is shown ... the problem is here
    }
echo '</div>';
```

**page-form.php** part of getting the result from **form.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#repeater_form').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/formResult.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#success_result').html(data);
                }
            })
        });

    });
```

Comment: What is the actual error here? Is this done in some wordpress setup? else do_shortcode isn't a php function. Or did you test that $(this).serialize() gets the correct data?

Comment: there is no error, it doenst get anything back. It is a WP site but im not using its functions here. The problem is in the `echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.$row["ID"].'"]');` except that everything is good

Comment: Can we load shortcode via ajax ?